# Pusher Android Subscribed Channel Twice

Tags: android, pusher

I am a newbie for Android and Pusher.

We just migrated Pusher in Android Native App. However, we are facing a problem with the subscribed the Channel Twice(I think the connection will be twice too).

Checked that we just create the pusher object under the onCreate and establish the connection.

We also added the pusher.subscribe under onResume and unsubscribe under onPause, onDestroy.
As document said An exception will be throw when subscribe twice.

When I start the apps. I checked the logs with the attached debug message. 
Showing two connections.

[image: Pusher Debug Console]

The attached file is my MainApp. Anyone can help? Many thanks. :) .....
* all subscribe and unsubscribed is added try .. catch .. exception now.

Thanks all. Since we are working this issue nearly 5 days...... Thanks all again and again.

2013-08-12 Update:
Hi all, i just amend the log and retest the program. The following is my result:

[image: Log from web service]
I checked that the connection is from connecting to connected once only. However, the pusher debug console show me:

[image: Pusher Debug Console] - The Channel: 2235d980e0621a54

It is quite strange. We are still investigating this issue.

The updated new source is here:
[Latest Source - MainActivity](http://www.sendspace.com/file/od2deb)

Answer (score 0):

A few clarifications:

1. When you create a new `Pusher` instance and call `connect` you establish a connection.
2. When you call `pusher.subscribe('channel');` you create a subscription to a channel - not a connection

The code you've provided subscribes to the same channel in both the `onCreate` and the `onResume`. You don't need to resubscribe in `onResume` as the library handles this for you. This existing code could result in an exception being thrown. So, you can remove the `onResume` code and remove that problem.

I'm not sure why you would be seeing two connections. Could you please provide details of the client log from your application?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. :). We create a new Pusher instance and call connect is under onCreate. Which is achieveExpectedConnectionState() also in onConnectionStateChange().

Comment: I will try to remove the onResume first and will update here. Many thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Hi, my post is updated. Many thanks for your[@leggetter] help.

Comment: @Erwin did you get to the bottom of this?